# Import SysML Models with xml/xmi Format to a Graph database

Tags: xml, neo4j, uml, xmi, sysml

I am looking for a method to import SysML (UML) Models into Neo4J.
I am working with Xpath to extract the Elements and Relationships between them. 
Is there a good way to export the Elements structured from XML/XML files so they can be converted in simple CSV files and imported to a Graph database?

Answer (score 0):

The [APOC Load XML](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/export-import/load-xml/) functionality may be of interest to you